# Skip to end of CSS Animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have implemented a CSS3 animation that has a beginning and end state. Once the end state is reached, the animation stops and doesn't repeat. What I need to do is have a "skip to end" link that bypasses the entire animation, but displays that final state. Is it possible to do this via CSS3.

Here's the animated page: http://bit.ly/1csZq2d

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using Javascript only to toggle a class on the container to override the animation in two ways:

1. Overwrite the animation with a *separate* animation with the same end result, still setting the end state with `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`:
   http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/yzhLb
2. Toggle `animation: none` and manually add the styles that would be at the end of the animation:
   http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/Jpmkc

The first method might be easier to manage so you just edit all your `@keyframes` in one place with one just containing the end state. It also has the benefit of just speeding up the animation so that it completes quickly, but still transitions relatively smoothly.